# Is Cordova.js Necessary?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

If we do not need access to the device's camera, contacts, GPS, etc, is there any reason not to eliminate the cordova.js file? Maybe it would improve loading time. I successfully built and previewed the app commenting out its script tag and it seems to work fine, but maybe there is more to cordova.js than accessing those device api's that I don't know about.

Comment: If you don't need access to the device, is an App necessary? You could simply write a mobile web-page.

Comment: A mobile website wouldn't have the abilities in my comment below.

Comment: What do the plugins do?

Comment: Background service and push notifications

Comment: An push notifications aren't part of accessing the device?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect They access the device through plugins, and as far as I know, cordova.js is not necessary to use plugins

Comment: Which push notification plugin are you using?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect I already have to write background services for each platform so I was going to incorporate the push notifications.

Comment: Yes, but which plugin are you using? Are you sure it doesn't need Cordova.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect For whatever plugins I use, my own or others, I'll check on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use it, then no, you don't need it. But aren't you building a website then, essentially?

Cordova lets you build an app by embedding a browser in a platform-specific app, so you as an app developer can user JavaScript. Cordova.js provides transparent access to the various APIs to control the hardware, but if you don't use them, then you may not need Cordova.js.

But apart from device APIs, Cordova might also implement a standard browser JavaScript function that is missing from certain browsers ([polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill)). As far as I know Cordova doesn't do that out of the box, although there are plugins that do ([like this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customevent-polyfill), for example).

Still, when in doubt, in terms of performance it doesn't matter much. Cordova.js will be part of the application, so no download is necessary after installation. And loading a local js file in a browser isn't that much overhead, even on a phone.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the interface will be a website, but it will act like an app in that the user will have an icon dedicated to it, it will have the entire screen to itself, it will use plugins and run a REST service in the background, and it will provide push notifications, none of which a mobile website can do.

Comment: @JosephJohnston, you will likely want to store data on the mobile device. In either case, you will want to review the App Policies for both [Google](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) and [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). Specifically for Apple, it reads in section: *2.12) Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected* Best of Luck.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 That doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Take a native app that doesn't use the hardware, say a note-taking app. What if the same app were made with phonegap. This would be a _web site bundled as an App_ but why should it be rejected when it has the same function as the native app?

Comment: @JosephJohnston, We can't say it will be rejected, just that it could be rejected. The rules governing *anything* are applied at the discretion of the rule creators. If this fictitious App were just a facade of a website, then I would say - yes they will likely reject it. If however, it provided some kind of mobile ability, let's say to post comments remotely, then it might have a better chance to get in. *Lastly*, I don't write the rules or enforce them for Google or Apple. FWIW: there is a 300ms delay on mobile websites when pressing a button on Android devices. This is a solved problem.